# Database which doesn't need a Private Key to Push Data

Tags: node.js, database, web-services, web, iot

I have a project I am working on which will be open source. The project records data from all over. People can look at the instructions on a website, build the prototype, and the prototype will contribute its data to a giant database.

[data.sparkfun.com/](https://data.sparkfun.com/) is perfect for this, except for a major problem. In order to push data, you need to put the Private Key in the code ([docs](http://phant.io/docs/input/http/)). This will also allow anybody with the code (which will be everybody looking at my project because it is open source) to edit, modify, and delete data from the database because they have the Private Key.

Is there any alternative to [data.sparkfun](http://data.sparkfun.com/) for free so that I can achieve this? I am using NodeJS as the main language for my project.

**EDIT:** I also do not have a server to host my own database on. I also would need a hosting service (which is why data.sparkfun is so close to what I need).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something called [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) which is hosted by Google. It has a full suite of databases, filesystems, and a way to identify users. You need an API Key for posting and retrieving data, but it is not meant to be private. It also allows you to set rules to disallow editing and deleting data, unless you own the database.

It supports iOS apps, Android Apps, and Web Apps (easy to integrate with NodeJS). The free version has some limitations, but enough for most hobbyists.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this project http://docs.dat-data.com/ could work.  It is built with Node.  Its not necessarily perfect because its a bit more oriented towards files than a database, but you may be able to adapt it to your application.  It uses cryptography and versioning for security.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but unfortunately I do not have a server to host the database.

Comment: Can run in the browser.